# Retrieve user informations from cognito with ID

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a simple blog with the AWS services in order to educate myself.

I am using Amazon Cognito to log in users. Every user have a nickname. I want my user to be able to post articles to my blog.

In order to store the articles, I am using DynamoDB. Here is a sample for an article item:

```
{
  "ArticleID": "MyUniqueID",
  "title": "My Hello World Article",
  "content": "This is the content of the article",
  "author": "26a16b31-b2c0-4cf3-89f9-d5dcfd56d530" // Cognito User ID.
}
```

I'm using the serverless framework and the lambda functions to create a REST API to retrieve the documents from the database.

Now, I want to display the nickname of an author on the article page of my blog. So I somewhere have to retrieve the nickname of the `26a16b31-b2c0-4cf3-89f9-d5dcfd56d530` user.

**How can I do that?**

Possibilities I tried to imagine:

- Using the Cognito Sync API in order to store the user informations in a DynamoDB table and add endpoints to my API to get those items.
- Don't use the attributes from cognito and create a "UserProfile" externalized service
- Creating an endpoint on my API to retrieve the public profile of a user (the lambda function would query the Amazon Cognito API and filter the public from the private attributes.)

**How would you do that? What is the best practice for that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created a serverless app using Cognito as authentication and I am using the second option you mention. It no only makes the data consistent, but easier to get.

If you keep attributes in your UserPool it will be like managing a third party API to get his data, while the third party could be just for the authentication.
You can always keep your user data in your localstorage session.

It is much more an architectural decision than a best practice.